# How can I graph this in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

The expression is this:

$|3z+2| \leq 1$

then, I did

$|3x+2+3iy| \leq 1$

and I got stuck.

Comment: Think of $z$ not just as a complex number here, but as a vector with a magnitude and a direction undergoing two transformations to become vector $v$; first $z$ is being dilated by length 3, and then being translated rightward by length 2.  The locus of $v$ such that their magnitude is less than length of 1 is easier to visualize, and you can work backwards from there.

Comment: Thank you. That way to analyze the problem made me think better

Comment: Try to think of it as a ball centered at a point. bring a 3 over to the other side and you will see what the center and radius are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: How do you find the modulus of a complex number?

Comment: "$(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$" sory for these fool questions, I should think more before asking here. Now I know how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: After all, I should remove the square roots so I can operate the inequation, right?

Comment: As you know the modulus is positive, you can square both sides of the inequality.